# Case classes in Scala Swing

Tags: swing, scala, case-class

I've been reading this chapter from a [Scala book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/gui-programming.html) and it says that:

> pressing a button will create an event which is an instance of the following case class:
>   `case class ButtonClicked(source: Button)`
>
> The parameter of the case class refers to the button that was clicked. As with all other Scala Swing events, this event class is contained in a package named scala.swing.event.

and then this code, where b is the actual button that was pressed:

```
case ButtonClicked(b) => //code
```

I looked at the API and sure enough, there was a constructor for ButtonPressed:

```
new ButtonClicked(source: AbstractButton)
```

So what happens to a mouse event, for example mousePressed? You usually do this in the code:

1) `case e: MousePressed => // code//`

Does that mean the below can also be done? Are they the same?

2) `case MousePressed(e: java.awt.event.MouseEvent)`

What's the difference between 1 and 2?

EDIT:

Is 1) also a case class? You don't have to pass a parameter into it?

Comment: Case classes and pattern matching are general (and widely-used) features of Scala, they're not specific to Scala Swing. You can read about them [in another chapter of the book you linked](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html), or, probably better in terms of being up-to-date, on the main [Scala doc page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering though why MousePressed is a case class when you write it like 1)? You don't have to pass it anything as in the EditDone case class..

Comment: OK, that actually excuses an answer ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being [a case class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) is just that - it's an **inherent quality of the class, not dependent on how you use it**. As you can see, [`MousePressed` is defined as a case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.swing.event.MousePressed) (and it's not a subclass of [Java's `MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) BTW, in case that causes confusion), so it's **always** a case class.

1 and 2 are simply different [pattern matching expressions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html). The difference is that:

- you can use 1 for **any** type, since you're basically saying "match anything that is an instance of the type `MousePressed`",
- for 2 you need something called [an extractor](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) - it tells Scala how to decompose the pattern you've provided. Case classes have constructor-derived extractors defined "for free", and that's why you're able to use 2 on `MousePressed`.

In summary - read up the previous chapter [on case classes and pattern matching](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html) - everything will become clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I've read up on the subject and it's more clear now. However I still have one more question: since there are two case class constructors for MousePressed, which one is used when a MousePressed event object needs to be created?

Comment: @SonicProtein You're welcome :). Created? Either one, case classes behave like normal classes in this case. If you meant to ask about matching - only the default constructor (the one in the "header") gets the "free `unapply` for case class" treatment - if the author of the class didn't add custom extractor logic, it will be the only one. In either case, you can check by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0-RC5/src/swing/scala/swing/event/MouseEvent.scala#L1), or just guessing - if you've guessed wrong, the compiler will complain and suggest the right one.

Comment: Please see the second edit in the question, I must still be confused about the whole thing :/

Comment: Actually I will just create a new question for this since this one is getting too long